# Finding out if ResourceRequest is AJAX request

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, portlet

Is there a way to find out if a [`ResourceRequest`](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/ResourceRequest.html) is an AJAX request?

We're using [JBoss RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) 3.3.3, [JBoss Portlet Bridge](http://www.jboss.org/portletbridge) 2.1 and [Java Portlet API 2.0](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return !StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getParameter("AJAXREQUEST"));
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request comes with a special header called X-Requested-With which should equal "XMLHttpRequest". So the cross framework way could be:

```
public static boolean isAjaxRequest(ResourceRequest request) {
   String request_header = request.getProperty("X-Requested-With");
   return (request_header!=null)&&(request_header.equalsIgnoreCase("XMLHttpRequest"));
}
```

The problem is some Ajax request might come without this header and different portal containers might implement this differently.

This is from the Java document for PortletRequest:

> getProperty
>
> java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String name)
>
> Returns the value of the specified request property as a String. If the request did not include a property of the specified name, this
>   method returns null.
>   A portlet can access portal/portlet-container
>   specific properties through this method and, if available, the headers
>   of the HTTP client request.